# Generate PDF from html file on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

In my iPhone application I'm generating an HTML file. I would like to convert that HTML file to a PDF file programatically. The PDF will then be attached to an email.

Does anyone know (have an example) how to convert the HTML file to a PDF?

Comment: I would REALLY love an answer to this. I am having a hard time solving this exact problem.

Comment: I'm on the same boat. How did you finally end-up solving this problem?

Answer (score 3):

maybe you should start from here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what your looking for it helped me because it's much easier to generate a prepared html doc then PDF for me.  I found a library that does that here http://maniacdev.com/2013/09/ios-library-for-easy-pdf-creation-from-an-html-string-or-URL